# syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have a function i.e

```
function cdec($num) {
for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++) {
$temp = $num[$n];
$dec = $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) – $n – 1);
}
return $dec;
}
```

When I am going to run my code then it is showing me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING)

I don't understand where is my fault. It is showing error in this line

> $dec = $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) – $n – 1);

Comment: What language? Please tag your question with it

Comment: minus (`-`) and hyphen (`–`) are different characters

Comment: I have make it like $dec = $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) ( - ) $n ( – ) 1);  still showing me another errror Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in

Comment: @IndreshTayal Yeah, but you need to change that back to a `-` character.

Comment: I am working in php language

Comment: @IndreshTayal Please use the **edit** link below your question and add the [tag:php] tag.

Comment: Hi Indresh
In regards to your previous comment, Arithmetic Operators do not work inside Parenthesis (Brackets) alone, they need data to operate on. What I mean by this is:
1 ( + ) 1; will not work.
(1 + 1 ); will work.
1 + 1; will work;

The issue, as pointed out by Naveed Ramzan, is that you are not using minus signs (-) but hyphens instead, which are for use in literacy.

While I do not come with the answer myself, it was important to correct your use of brackets around Arithmetic Operators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cdec($num) {
    $dec = '';
    for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++) {
        $temp = $num[$n];
        $dec = $dec + $temp*pow(2 , strlen($num) - $n - 1);
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

Both Minus signs were in fact Hyphen signs.

Comment: I have used you function, Now It is showing Undefined variable: dec

Comment: OK in fact, that is because we were defined $dec in loop. so I defined in before loop and now see.

Comment: Thanks, Now it is working properly

Comment: Welcome, you can mark answer and also upvote.

Answer (score -1):

Use parenthesis to separate math operations:

```
function cdec($num) {
    $dec = 0;
    for ($n = 0 ; $n < strlen($num) ; $n++) {
        $temp = $num[$n];
        $dec = $dec + ($temp*(pow(2 , ((strlen($num) - $n) - 1))));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```